# How to get a specific class/xpath data using request in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get only the price of the coin but instead, I am getting the whole HTML because of the body.
I cannot find any documentation or usage for the request package so I needed to ask here.

I am trying to find the class="price" which only shows the price.

Is there a way to search based on class or the XPath of the URL or a way to cut everything out except for the class="price" section?

```
const request = require('request')

request('https://www.livecoinwatch.com/price/Spark-FLR', function (
  error,
  response,
  body
) {
  console.error('error:', error)
  console.log('body:', body)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you get the doctument，find a package like jquery parse it，find the price。

like this：

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const {document} = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')).window; //the document
global.document = document;
const window = document.defaultView;
const $ = require('jquery')(window);
```